# Android native debug, ndk-gdb libraries not found

Tags: android, gdb, java-native-interface

I have an Android application with JNI (and SWIG).
The application runs fine and I can debug the java and the native code,
but I keep having warnings from gdb that I have no idea where they come from,
I stripped the code down to a very simple function.
I followed various tutorials on how to do that,
I tried on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Linux mint 12, I'm using eclipse (ADT).

That's the warnings I got:

```
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 63 libraries, e.g.   /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().
[New Thread 17108]
[New Thread 17110]
[New Thread 17112]
[New Thread 17113]
[New Thread 17114]
[New Thread 17115]
[New Thread 17116]
[New Thread 17117]
[New Thread 17118]
[Switching to Thread 17106]
```

I have no idea which libraries gdb is looking for,
any idea??

here is the output of info sharedlibrary

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x40003220  0x4000b940  Yes (*)     /home/andrea/workspace/pjsip_app/obj/local/armeabi/linker
0x4002c860  0x4005c07c  Yes (*)     /home/andrea/workspace/pjsip_app/obj/local/armeabi/libc.so
                        No          libstdc++.so
                        No          libm.so
                        No          liblog.so
                        No          libcutils.so
                        No          libgccdemangle.so
                        No          libcorkscrew.so
                        No          libz.so
                        No          libutils.so
                        No          libbinder.so
                        No          libemoji.so
                        No          libjpeg.so
                        No          libexpat.so
                        No          libskia.so
                        No          libandroidfw.so
                        No          libstlport.so
                        No          libnativehelper.so
                        No          libnetutils.so
                        No          libhardware.so
                        No          libsync.so
                        No          libui.so
                        No          libGLES_trace.so
                        No          libEGL.so
                        No          libGLESv2.so
                        No          libgui.so
                        No          libcamera_client.so
                        No          libgabi++.so
                        No          libicuuc.so
                        No          libicui18n.so
                        No          libsqlite.so
                        No          libdvm.so
                        No          libGLESv1_CM.so
                        No          libETC1.so
                        No          libwpa_client.so
                        No          libhardware_legacy.so
                        No          libsonivox.so
                        No          libcrypto.so
                        No          libssl.so
                        No          libstagefright_foundation.so
                        No          libspeexresampler.so
                        No          libaudioutils.so
                        No          libmedia_native.so
                        No          libmedia.so
                        No          libusbhost.so
                        No          libharfbuzz.so
                        No          libhwui.so
                        No          libandroid_runtime.so
                        No          libjavacore.so
                        No          libdrmframework.so
                        No          libdrmframework_jni.so
                        No          libstagefright_omx.so
                        No          libstagefright_yuv.so
                        No          libvorbisidec.so
                        No          libstagefright_enc_common.so
                        No          libstagefright_avc_common.so
                        No          libstagefright.so
                        No          libmtp.so
                        No          libexif.so
                        No          libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
                        No          libmedia_jni.so
                        No          libbcinfo.so
                        No          libbcc.so
                        No          libRS.so
                        No          librs_jni.so
                        No          libandroid.so
                        No          libchromium_net.so
                        No          libwebcore.so
                        No          libwilhelm.so
                        No          libOpenSLES.so
0x47ceb0f8  0x47e7fd98  Yes         /home/andrea/workspace/pjsip_app/obj/local/armeabi/libconnection.so
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

Comment: Add the result of `info sharedlibrary`.  The missing symbols are probably form system libraries.  Most likely you can ignore the errors as long as debug symbols were found for your library.

Comment: thanks, I added the output of info sharedlibrary

Comment: Looks normal to me.  The other libs are Android libs found on the device.  Unless you are debugging an Android issue the extra symbols are not needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In fact, I can debug my Native code, this is all I want. Just being curious, where could I get those libraries? Are they somewhere in the android NDK? Or would I have to compile the Android source code?

Comment: You should be able to build them from the AOSP.  Each platform has a release, engineering, and debug target.

Comment: Check this question, It could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532229/android-gdb-is-not-loading-c-shared-library/21533990#21533990